# Why does Google stipulate that you specify whether you are using a sensor in the maps API?

Tags: api, google-maps, sensors

When retrieving the Google Maps API javascript, Google requires that you specify whether you are using a sensor or not with your application (e.g. `sensor=false`).  Why is this?  Is it simply a matter of data collection so Google can approximate how the API is being used, or does it actually modify what is returned in some instances?

Comment: @Pete - if it returns something different, it could be device/environment specific.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/premier/guide.html#Sensor), the `sensor` option is to determine if you are using a GPS-Enabled / location tracking device. The `sensor=false` maps are more light-weight since they don't handle this additional functionality. As you mentioned, the `sensor=true` maps handle device specific location tracking, etc.

Comment: Do you have any examples of where something different is returned when sensor=true is specified?

Comment: Diff the apiLoad line between http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true and http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false or try copying the location tracking sample and toggling the sensor flag